# I want auto labeling with auctex+reftex

Tags: labels, emacs, auctex, reftex, ref

So first, i define new environment (or new theorem)  like

```
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
```

For convenience, I want

C-c C-e cor RET

then it display

```
\begin{cor}
\label{cor:*document name*:number}

\end{cor}
```

For align environment, it really did auto labeling but for others i don't know how to do

I manage to do config label prefix rule 
( if i do C-c ( inside cor enviroment then `\label{cor:*document name*:number}` appears) ,which is already nice but typing C-c ( every time is time-consuming i think.

I thought it will be cool that emacs automatically create label for thm,cor,prop...etc just like equation

Plz help me

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Off-topic: you could use code style button

Comment: @Bobyandbob an MWE does not really make sense here, as this is not really a LaTeX problem, but rather a question for an editor.

Comment: You are probably more likely to get help on this issue, if you ask on the auctex/reftex (this part is reftex domain) mailing list, se https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/mailing-lists.html

Comment: thanks! i thought it is related to latex but as i see your responses it might be not. It is a problem somewhere between emacs and latex... tricky.  If anyone has a idea, plz continue to reply. Ah, and i will follow MWE next time. It's my first time to post, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Emacs to do what you want by making additions to the variables `LaTeX-label-alist` **and** `reftex-label-alist`.  I don't recommend putting these changes in your `.emacs`, I would add them as local variables to your `.tex` file (or even better write your own AUCTeX style file for it).

Your file can look like this -- note that I use `ntheorem` for new definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% eval: (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist '("cor" . "cor:"))
%%% eval: (add-to-list 'reftex-label-alist '("cor" ?c "cor:%f:" "~\ref{%s}" nil ("Corollary" "corollary") nil))
%%% End:
```

When you load this file, Emacs will ask you if you want to apply the local variables, say <kbd>y</kbd>.  Next, hit <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> to parse the file and enter <kbd>C-c C-e cor RET RET</kbd>.  The result should look like this:

[image]

Please read RefTeX manual regarding the details about [`reftex-label-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#IDX276).

Comment: thanks. What i want to find is LaTeX-label-alist! ( I think the second "cor:" must be the prefix rule for labeling but i strongly guess that reftex overwrite it to cor:%f:)    Also, i could learn file variable( local variable) in emacs this time. Really appreciate.